Inkwell splash color still showing after setting it to transparent
I have an Inkwell widget, and I am trying to make the splash and highlight colors transparent, so that I do not see them. This usually works fine by setting the Color property to transparent, but it does not work here. I have tried using WidgetStateColor.transparent as well, but that also does not work. Any help is appreciated.
Code for the Inkwell:
return InkWell(
      overlayColor: WidgetStateColor.transparent,
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      onTap: handleTap,
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 10,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: null),
        child: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              incrementCounter();
            },
            child: Text(
              '${scrambles[counter % scrambles.length]}',
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
          // child: Text('Ignore this)
          //     ),
        ),
      ),
    );


You can use GestureDetector

It seems as if Inkwell is not the issue, rather, TextButton. Try out this code:
child: TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
              overlayColor: WidgetStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.transparent),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              incrementCounter();
            },

This should allow for the 'splashColor' of the TextButton to be transparent, therefore solving your issue.
